# How do I determine what line of my javascript is causing this error in IE, when the console reports the bug is in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I have a complex web application which is working in modern web browsers and IE10. I'm testing in older versions of IE7 now and running into a bug which stops the page from fully loading. The only error I can see on the screen is:

```
 SCRIPT5022: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 
  jquery.min.js, line 3 character 14659
```

Which points to:

```
{throw new Error("Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "+a)}
```

I have no idea what part of my javascript is triggering this. The code base is huge so I don't know where to even begin. Are there any tricks or standard methods to help me? No errors or problems are reported in Chrome, Firefox, Safari (latest versions) or IE10. I am using IE10 in ie 7 mode... the problem also persist in ie 7 ran in a virtual machine.

Thanks.

Edit: I am running jQuery 1.7 from this source: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? If you're using at least 2.0, it doesn't support old versions of IE anymore

Comment: jQuery 1.7 from this source: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 1):

If your codebase is too big for you to step through it until you find the jQuery-operation that leads to the error, try searching your jQuery-selectors for a `TAB`-character.

I had the same problem (in IE7 only) when using jQuery 1.7.1. I found a selector that contained a `TAB`-character (in the middle of the selector) and once removed, all was well.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Ian's point about jquery v2 - my understanding is that the line number is relative to a page with all the included JS files just being inlined.

So, take your browser view source, and then for each script src you have, remove that and copy in the actual JS file content (possibly wrapping in script tags I guess??).

Good luck!

Btw might be worth trying in IE8 or IE9 running in IE7 mode as they have better debuggers.

Comment: Hi, I don't know if this helps narrow down the problem but the problem is not present in IE8 or IE9.